# How do I bind a keystroke to be executed in another Emacs window?

Tags: emacs

Now I really, really happy knowing that Emacs can replace Netbeans for my Java Web development and also J2ME development. I need some getting used to. And when it does, it's very fun!

And now I need to send a command in Shell Window, that is `ant deploy` and I want to binding it to, say, `F5`. How do I do this? because everytime I did, it execute in active buffer. So, I must switch to that shell, before pressing `F5`. Can I press `F5` in any window, but it execute in certain shell window ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement something like

```
(defun my-ant-run ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (get-buffer "shell-ant-run")
(shell (get-buffer-create "shell-ant-run")))
  (process-send-string (get-buffer-process "shell-ant-run") "ant deploy\n"))
```

and bind it to F5

```
  (global-set-key [f5] 'my-ant-run)
```

Comment: It's working allright. Now, suppose the command `ant deploy` should be started in a certain folder, say, `e:\Project\CerdasCAT`, how do I accomplish this?
Sorry, I got this working already. using this code (it's a MS Windows environment) : 
`(process-send-string (get-buffer-process "CerdasCAT") "e:\ncd E:/_Siswa/Rukli/CerdasCAT\nant deploy\n")`